# Replace text in Word VBA based on Multiple Font Conditions

Tags: vba, fonts, ms-word

I am trying to delete all the words with font. name.FarEast="Georgia" and font.name="Verdana", Bold=true in the document, but I cannot find any find function for vba...(I'm ok with manually set the find formating)
can anyone help me with that?

I have depleted my method of searching and could not find an answer

```
 With Selection.Find.Bold = True
        .ClearFormatting
        Selection.Font.NameFarEast = "Georgia"
       .Font.Name = "Verdana"
       .Execute FindText:="", ReplaceWith:="", Format:=True, _
        Forward:=True
        End With
```

'seems don't work at all

it just shows

> "method or data not found"

Comment: For another time you can record the `Find` actions in a macro to get started. I imagine the problem with the code in the question is that a new line needs to come before `.Bold = True`. For future problems with error messages it would help us to mention *which line of code* causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can loop through all the words and check for the condition.**

```
Sub test1()

Dim sen As Object
Dim wd As Object

For Each sen In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(1).Sentences

    For Each wd In sen.Words

        With wd
        If .Bold = True  And .Font.Name = "Verdana" And .Font.NameFarEast = "Georgia" Then

            wd.Select
            Selection.Text = ""

        End If
        End With

    Next

Next

End Sub
```

**Demo:** *Only Checking the Bold Words*

[image]